# ¿Cómo introducir y recoger datos de la tabla intermedia y mostarlos en la tabla php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, formularios

Tengo el diagrama relacional siguiente: [image: Diagrama ER]

Y tengo un formulario junto una tabla php que introduce los datos propios de la tabla libro. Lo que necesito es que además, pueda desde ese mismo formulario mediante un multiselect, elegir a cuantos géneros pertenece el libro y que me los me los muestre en la misma tabla php como otra columna más. ¿Cómo se podría hacer?

Edito: Ya tengo casi solventado todos los problemas que tenía. Solo me falta cómo mostrar el género agrupado por comas, junto con el resto de la consulta. Tengo ahora el siguiente diagrama de tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para mostrar las columnas que me interesan en una mismas tabla tengo el codigo siguiente:

```
<tr>
       <th colspan="6"><h2> Juego </h2></th>
       </tr>
       <tr> 
           <br>
           <td>id</td>
           <td>Nombre</td>
           <td>Edad</td>
           <td>Precio</td>
           <td>Editorial</td>
           <td>Género</td>
       </tr>

       <?php 

       $sql="SELECT tbl_libro.*, tbl_genero.nom_genero, tbl_editorial.nombre_editorial
       FROM tbl_libro 
       INNER JOIN tbl_libro_genero 
       ON tbl_libro.id_libro=tbl_libro_genero.id_libro 
       INNER JOIN tbl_genero 
       ON tbl_libro_genero.id_genero=tbl_genero.id_genero 
       INNER JOIN tbl_editorial
       ON tbl_libro.id_editorial=tbl_editorial.id_editorial";


       $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

       while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       ?>

       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['id_libro'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre_libro'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['edad'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['precio_libro'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre_editorial'] ?>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['nom_genero'] ?>
           </td>
       </tr>       

   <?php } ?>
```

Pero dado que géneros hay más de uno. me muestra tantas filas duplicadas como géneros tiene dicho libro. Por lo tanto, en mi base de datos he probado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT u.id_libro, u.nombre_libro, s.nom_genero
        Group_concat(s.nom_genero)
        FROM   tbl_libro u
        INNER JOIN tbl_libro_genero us
               ON u.id_libro = us.id_libro 
        INNER JOIN tbl_genero s
               ON us.id_genero = s.id_genero
        GROUP  BY u.id_libro
```

Lo que necesito es introducir la consulta en la variable $sql junto con el resto, en lugar de la consulta que hay ahora para la columna genero.

Espero haberme explicado con claridad, si no cualquier cosa decidme.

Comment: Con un select con el atributo multiple.

Comment: @JDev. Yo me refería a la instrucción sql que combinada con el atributo que comentas asocia el libro junto al género para después mostrarlo por pantalla mediante una columna en la tabla.

Comment: Muéstranos algo de código para que sea más fácil replicar lo que tienes y tratar de llegar a lo deseas lograr. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te des una idea de cómo elaborar una pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: @DjCrazy. Hecho,  espero haber estado más acertado esta vez. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que hagas una consulta para obtener la información del libro y otra para obtener los  géneros del libro, vinculando la tabla intermedia libro_genero con la tabla de género, condicionada por el  Id del libro. Si haces la consulta en sql notaras que la información se repite dependiendo de el numero que géneros que tiene ese libro, cuando la consultas desde php te arroja toda la información del libro, pero solo el primer género, así que es mejor hacer consultas separadas, el reto es que sepas organizar la tabla con las 2 consultas.

Comment: Deberias acompañar tu respuesta con codigo, de esta forma al leerlo rapido me parecio confusa la respuesta.